# Parse JSON result with Attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Inside a decoded JSON I have also a sub list with:

```
"steps": [{
    "id": 54785,
    "response": {
        "attributes": {
            "xsi:type”:”text1”},”message": {
                "attributes": {
                    "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
                },
                "$value": "alterMultipleParameter"
            },
            "nextcase": {
                "attributes": {
                    "xsi:type": "xsd:int"
                },
                "$value": 4823
            },
            "nextstep": {
                "attributes": {
                    "xsi:type": "xsd:int"
                },
                "$value": 54786
            },
            “myid ":{"
            attributes ":{"
            xsi: type ":"
            xsd: string "},"
            $value”: ”1234”
        },
        "tickaction": {
            "attributes": {
                "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
            },
            "$value": "httpok"
        },
        "miscellaneous": {
            "attributes": {
                "xsi:type": "xsd:string"
            },
            "$value": "eyJjb250YWluZXJwZCI6ZmFsc2UsInJlYWRhYmxlQWN0aW9uIjoiYWwdWx0aXBsZUNvcnB1c1BhcmFtZXRlciBLb3JwdXNfSG9laGUgMTAwMC4wMCIsIm5leHRBY3Rpb24iOiJhZGRGcm9udCJ9"
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": 54786….
}]
```

I know how to access the steps values and their id

```
for(y=0; y < myArr.finishedRuns[i].steps.length; y++)
{
console.log(myArr.finishedRuns[i].steps[y].id);
console.log(myArr.finishedRuns[i].steps[y].miscellaneous);
}
```

But how to get the value from miscellaneous? Currently I get "undefined" for the miscellaneous part.
miscellaneous.value will fail in an error.

Comment: Does it print id correctly?

Comment: And have you tried `myArr.finishedRuns[i].steps[y].miscellaneous['$value']`?

Comment: `myArr.finishedRuns[i].steps[y].response.miscellaneous` ?

Comment: After edit of your question, it is clearly visible that `miscellaneous` belongs to `response` so you need to type `myArr.finishedRuns[i].steps[y].response.miscellaneous['$value']`

Comment: thought this dosn't work because in your list of step. there is just id and responses which have values subvalues. what would be your expected result ?

Comment: Many thanks Mirakurun. It was a wrong view to the data structure. Your moment help me out.!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use forEach:

```
steps.forEach(data => {
    console.log(data.response.miscellaneous);
  });
```